# Webkit2gtk not shown with gtk-layer-shell

Tags: rust, gtk, gtk3

I want to make a webkit window and show it as my wallpaper.

I found a workaround to create a webkit2gtk window as follows.

```rust
// [dependencies]
// gtk = "0.16.0"
// gtk-layer-shell = "0.5"
// webkit2gtk = "1.1.0"

use gtk::gdk;
use gtk::prelude::*;
use gtk::Application;
use gtk::ApplicationWindow;
use webkit2gtk::WebViewExt;

fn main() {
    let app = Application::new(None, Default::default());
    app.connect_activate(move |app| {
        let display = gdk::Display::default().unwrap();
        for i in 0..display.n_monitors() {
            let monitor = display.monitor(i).unwrap();
            let gtk_window = ApplicationWindow::new(app);
            gtk_window.set_default_size(1920, 1080);

            let webview = webkit2gtk::WebView::new();
            gtk_window.add(&webview);
            webview.load_uri("http://localhost:8081");

            // gtk_layer_shell::init_for_window(&gtk_window);
            // gtk_layer_shell::set_layer(&gtk_window, gtk_layer_shell::Layer::Background);
            // gtk_layer_shell::set_monitor(&gtk_window, &monitor);

            gtk_window.show_all();
        }
    });

    app.run();
}
```

The above code works fine and creates 2 webview windows (since I have 2 monitors). However, if I add some gtk_layer_shell operations to the code (as commented above), no window appears anywhere.

I'm wondering if this is some webkit2gtk bug or something wrong with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The window you create with layer shell needs to have size set and the `set_default_size` seems not doing its job.

Replace `gtk_window.set_default_size(1920, 1080);` with `gtk_window.set_size_request(1920, 1080);` and the window should show.

If you want to create fullscreen window with layer shell you can skip the size request and use anchors instead:

```
window.set_anchor(Edge::Left, true); 
window.set_anchor(Edge::Right, true);
window.set_anchor(Edge::Top, true);
window.set_anchor(Edge::Bottom, true);
```